# Get index of clicked row from a nested listview - UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a nested listview. When clicks on it's button I want to get it's row index. Now I got the index as -1 always.

```
   <ListView x:Name="Mainlist" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentBooksList">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ListView x:Name="sublist1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CurrentFoldersArray}" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentFoldersList">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind BookCode}"/>
                                        <ListView x:Name="sublist2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CurrentBookArray1}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentBusList1">
                                                    <Button Width="120" Height="40" Text="{x:Bind Lockbook}"  Click="LockMyBook_btn_Click">
                                                    </Button>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 private void LockMyBook_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndx = Mainlist.SelectedIndex; //always return -1
    }
```

How can I get the row number of mainlist view, when user clicks on it's inner listview's button?

Comment: I'm confused with your code. Were you sure that the button has `Text` property? Could you compile your code and run your code successfully? What did you want to do by getting the row number of the 'mainlist'?

Comment: Yes it runs well. By getting row number of mainlist, I want to access corresponding items in CurrentBooksList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes it runs well. By getting row number of mainlist, I want to access corresponding items in CurrentBooksList

Well, it's strange. If you're using a basic UWP button control, it doesn't have `Text` property, your code should not work. But I didn't care about this point, your question was not related to it.

In your button's click event handler, you could get its `DataContext`, then you could convert it to an `CurrentBusList1` object. By this `CurrentBusList1` object, you could do some judgements from your 'Mainlist' ItemsSource and get the selected `CurrentBooksList` object.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<CurrentBooksList> currentBooksLists { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        currentBooksLists = new ObservableCollection<CurrentBooksList>();

        ObservableCollection<CurrentFoldersList> currentFoldersLists = new ObservableCollection<CurrentFoldersList>();
        currentFoldersLists.Add(new CurrentFoldersList() { BookCode = "abc123", CurrentBookArray1 = new ObservableCollection<CurrentBusList1>() { new CurrentBusList1() { Lockbook = "123abc" }, new CurrentBusList1() { Lockbook = "123def" } } });
        currentFoldersLists.Add(new CurrentFoldersList() { BookCode = "def456", CurrentBookArray1 = new ObservableCollection<CurrentBusList1>() { new CurrentBusList1() { Lockbook = "def456" } } });


        currentBooksLists.Add(new CurrentBooksList() { CurrentFoldersArray = currentFoldersLists });
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index;
        var subSelectedItem = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as CurrentBusList1;

        foreach (var item in currentBooksLists)
        {
            foreach (var folder in item.CurrentFoldersArray)
            {
                foreach (var bus in folder.CurrentBookArray1)
                {
                    if (bus == subSelectedItem)
                    {
                        index = currentBooksLists.IndexOf(item);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CurrentBooksList
{
    public ObservableCollection<CurrentFoldersList> CurrentFoldersArray { get; set; }

}

public class CurrentFoldersList
{
    public string BookCode { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CurrentBusList1> CurrentBookArray1 { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentBusList1
{
    public string Lockbook { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<ListView x:Name="Mainlist" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{x:Bind currentBooksLists}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentBooksList">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ListView x:Name="sublist1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CurrentFoldersArray}" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentFoldersList">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind BookCode}"/>
                                    <ListView x:Name="sublist2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CurrentBookArray1}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentBusList1">
                                                <Button Width="120" Height="40" Content="{x:Bind Lockbook}" Click="Button_Click">
                                                </Button>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: using above code I can access the datas on CurrentBusList1. but I want to get the clicked button's row index.

Comment: @nsds Your ultimate goal is to get the selcted CurrentBooksList object. You did not need to get the row index.

Comment: no I want it's row number for executing a different function

Comment: @nsds If you have to get the index, please see my updated code.